# SoapClient does not generate correct Request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have the SOAP endpoint and I would like to use PHP's \SoapClient class to send the request. The problem is that even if the "senderAddress" attribute has eg. "name", "nameDetail", "type" attributes (some of them are required by the docs), the generated XML request does not contain them. The only attribute it accepts/generates is the "id" attribute.

The same problem is also in another parts of the shipment object - f.ex. The Pickup part allows me to set just the "date" attribute, all of the others are skipped/ignored.

I've prepared some dummy code below, without data objects, just a simple array:

```
<?php
$soapClient = new \SoapClient("https://capi.dpdportal.sk/apix/shipment/?wsdl", [
    'trace' => 1
]);
$headers = array();
$dpdSecurity = new \stdClass();
$token = new \stdClass();
$token->ClientKey = "topsecretkey";
$token->Email = "topsecretmail";
$dpdSecurity->SecurityToken = $token;
$headers["auth"] = new \SoapHeader('http://www.dpdportal.sk/XMLSchema/DPDSecurity/v2', 'DPDSecurity', $dpdSecurity);
$soapClient->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
$shipment = [
    "reference" => "123",
    "delisId" => "123",
    "addressSender" => [
        "type" => "b2c", // this attribute is missing in the Request
        "id" => 41656415651,
        "nameDetail" => "test", // this attribute is missing in the Request
    ],
    "addressRecipient" => "123",
    "product" => 9,
    "parcels" => [],
    "pickup" => null,
];
$params = [
    'shipment' => $shipment,
];
try {
    $response = $soapClient->CreateV1($params);
    echo '==' . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($response);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Generated Request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.dpdportal.sk/XMLSchema/SHIPMENT/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://www.dpdportal.sk/XMLSchema/DPDSecurity/v2">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <ns2:DPDSecurity>
         <ns2:SecurityToken>
            <ns2:ClientKey>topsecretkey</ns2:ClientKey>
            <ns2:Email>topsecretmail</ns2:Email>
         </ns2:SecurityToken>
      </ns2:DPDSecurity>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:CreateRequest>
         <ns1:shipment>
            <ns1:reference>123</ns1:reference>
            <ns1:delisId>123</ns1:delisId>
            <ns1:product>9</ns1:product>
            <ns1:pickup />
            <ns1:addressSender>
               <ns1:id>41656415651</ns1:id>
            </ns1:addressSender>
            <ns1:addressRecipient />
            <ns1:parcels />
         </ns1:shipment>
      </ns1:CreateRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Shipment v1 schema](https://api.dpdportal.sk/xsd_schema/ShipmentSchema_v1.xsd) states that the `addressSender` element is of type `SHIPMENT:addressEnvelope`, which is defined as such:

```
<xsd:complexType name="addressEnvelope">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Address envelope</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="id" type="SHIPMENT:idType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Address ID</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>

        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="type" type="SHIPMENT:addresstypeType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="name" type="SHIPMENT:nameType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Contact person</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="nameDetail" type="SHIPMENT:nameType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Contact person (detail)</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="street" type="SHIPMENT:streetType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="streetDetail" type="SHIPMENT:streetType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Street (detail)</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="houseNumber" type="SHIPMENT:houseNumberType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="zip" type="SHIPMENT:zipType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="country" type="SHIPMENT:countryType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="city" type="SHIPMENT:cityType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="phone" type="SHIPMENT:phoneType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="email" type="SHIPMENT:emailType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="reference" type="SHIPMENT:referenceType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Reference for address (e.g. specific code of client)</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="note" type="SHIPMENT:noteType" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>Free note related to address</xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>

            <xsd:element name="ico" type="SHIPMENT:icoType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="vatId" type="SHIPMENT:vatIdType" minOccurs="0" />

            <xsd:element name="vatId2" type="SHIPMENT:vatId2Type" minOccurs="0" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Since the `addressEnvelope` is a choice, you are only allowed to define one of the sequences. Since your data includes an `id`, the SoapClient uses the first sequence.

**Update**
Upon further testing, I can conclude that `SoapClient` will never choose the second sequence, since the first sequence only has an optional `id` element, which results in any data you provide being valid.
The only way I was able to force `SoapClient` to choose the second sequence is by changing the `minOccurs` value of the `id` element to `1`.
To do this, you will have to download both the WSDL file and Shipment v1 schema, host them locally, and update the URLs.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't mention that in the question, but the element "id" is the only one which occurs in the result, even if I define all the attributes from the second sequence and do not provide the service with the id, the addressSender element will be empty.

Comment: Indeed, it will be empty, because the first sequence contains only an optional id. I think that `SoapClient` will therefore always choose the first sequence, because it is always valid. I've tested your code myself and was only able to make it work by changing the `minOccurs` of the `id` element to `1` in `ShipmentSchema_v1.xsd`. You will have to host both the wsdl file and xsd file locally and point to the local wsdl file when instantiating the `SoapClient`.

Comment: Also note that your `"addressRecipient" => "123"` is invalid. You need to change it to `"addressRecipient" => ["id" => 123],` to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I know that the addressRecipient is invalid, thanks.

Comment: I had to update the XSD and store it locally in the end.